# How to add image into menu Title?

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to add image into menu item title.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:showIn="navigation_view">

  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_admin"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_admin"
      android:title="管理画面"/>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_link"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_link"
      android:title="このアプリについて" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
      android:title="ログアウト" />

  </group>

</menu>
```

Here after title name i want to add an image in the menu. How can i do that?

Comment: did you solved it...?

Answer (score 0):

Just create your custom view and then add that to your menu item like this:

```
<item
     android:id="@+id/nav_admin"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_admin"
     android:title="管理画面"
     app:actionLayout="@layout/my_custom_item"
/>
```

**UPDATE:**

I usually change these thing in code:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                    AttributeSet attrs) {

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                    try {
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // set the text color, font, text size
                                Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                                        getAssets(),"OldeEnglish.ttf");     
                                ((TextView) view).setTypeface(face);
                                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(12);
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (InflateException e) {
                        //Handle any inflation exception here
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        //Handle any ClassNotFoundException here
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_admin:
            //something
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            //something
            break;
        case R.id.nav_link:
            //something
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zarei how can i change the style of the title?

Comment: What do mean by that?? You want to change the effect or font or what??

Comment: mostly font and textsize

Comment: @JasonBourne check my below ans

Comment: @Zarei can you add the factory import?

Comment: @JasonBourne `import android.view.LayoutInflater;`

Answer (score 0):

First create on IconizedMenu.Java

```
package project.student.dm.com.floatingactionbutton;

/**
 * Created by PatelD on 04-10-2017.
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPresenter;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Copied from android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.
 * "mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);" in the constructor does the trick :)
 *
 * @author maikvlcek
 * @since 5:00 PM - 1/27/14
 */
public class IconizedMenu implements MenuBuilder.Callback, MenuPresenter.Callback {
    private Context mContext;
    private MenuBuilder mMenu;
    private View mAnchor;
    private MenuPopupHelper mPopup;
    private OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener;
    private OnDismissListener mDismissListener;

    /**
     * Callback interface used to notify the application that the menu has closed.
     */
    public interface OnDismissListener {
        /**
         * Called when the associated menu has been dismissed.
         *
         * @param menu The PopupMenu that was dismissed.
         */
        public void onDismiss(IconizedMenu menu);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new PopupMenu.
     *
     * @param context Context for the PopupMenu.
     * @param anchor  Anchor view for this popup. The popup will appear below the anchor if there
     *                is room, or above it if there is not.
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public IconizedMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        mContext = context;
        mMenu = new MenuBuilder(context);
        mMenu.setCallback(this);
        mAnchor = anchor;
        mPopup = new MenuPopupHelper(context, mMenu, anchor);
        mMenu.setCallback(this);
        mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return the {@link android.view.Menu} associated with this popup. Populate the returned Menu with
     * items before calling {@link #show()}.
     * @see #show()
     * @see #getMenuInflater()
     */
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return mMenu;
    }

    /**
     * @return a {@link android.view.MenuInflater} that can be used to inflate menu items from XML into the
     * menu returned by {@link #getMenu()}.
     * @see #getMenu()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return new SupportMenuInflater(mContext);
    }

    /**
     * Inflate a menu resource into this PopupMenu. This is equivalent to calling
     * popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, popupMenu.getMenu()).
     *
     * @param menuRes Menu resource to inflate
     */
    public void inflate(int menuRes) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, mMenu);
    }

    /**
     * Show the menu popup anchored to the view specified during construction.
     *
     * @see #dismiss()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void show() {
        mPopup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Dismiss the menu popup.
     *
     * @see #show()
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void dismiss() {
        mPopup.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when the user selects an item from the menu.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        mMenuItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set a listener that will be notified when this menu is dismissed.
     *
     * @param listener Listener to notify
     */
    public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
        mDismissListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
        if (mMenuItemClickListener != null) {
            return mMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseMenu(MenuBuilder menu, boolean allMenusAreClosing) {
        if (mDismissListener != null) {
            mDismissListener.onDismiss(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public boolean onOpenSubMenu(MenuBuilder subMenu) {
        if (subMenu == null) return false;

        if (!subMenu.hasVisibleItems()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Current menu will be dismissed by the normal helper, submenu will be shown in its place.
        new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, subMenu, mAnchor).show();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onCloseSubMenu(SubMenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {
    }

    /**
     * Interface responsible for receiving menu item click events if the items themselves
     * do not have individual item click listeners.
     */
    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
        /**
         * This method will be invoked when a menu item is clicked if the item itself did
         * not already handle the event.
         *
         * @param item {@link MenuItem} that was clicked
         * @return <code>true</code> if the event was handled, <code>false</code> otherwise.
         */
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item);
    }

}
```

To show the menu,

```
IconizedMenu popup = new IconizedMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.pop_up, popup.getMenu());

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new IconizedMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
popup.show();//showing popup menu
```

Create pop_up.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Mathematics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Chemistry" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Physics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Biology" />
</menu>
```